# Generating a random number complying a specific pattern

Tags: php

I want to generate a number that contains 14 digits. But I want to generate it in a certain pattern. Consider the following number:

> **292** 0505 150 **0253**

- The bold numbers are  constants
- `0505` is a day and a month meaning `05` is the month and `05` is the day. So when generating the random number the first part must be from `0` to `12` and the second one from `1` to `31`
- The other number (`150`) is random

I want each attempt post to a page by curl.

Comment: Hm... Know what? I recently found out, that punctuational characters are available on my keyboard, too!

Comment: This question is hard to understand, but it seems like part of it involves picking a random date? If so, you'll want to somehow use PHP's date functions instead, since 02/31 is not a valid date.

Comment: You might want to break this into two parts: 1) generating the numbers you need and 2) posting with curl

Comment: It sounds like he needs 4 random numbers - (000-999)(01-12)(01-31)(0000000-9999999)

Comment: I tried to improve the wording, I hope I did not change the meaning, feel free to revert my changes. I was not sure about the last sentence though.

Comment: @Nathan Long: re: 2/31 not a real date.  Sure it is.  It's Mar 3.  Just ask `strtotime()` or `mktime()`.

Comment: @moustafa: The month part should either be 1-12 or 0-11, but not 0-12.  You'll find yourself mysteriously losing an entire month every year.  Unless you're subtly adding an International Fixed Calendar easter egg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function randomNumber($startDate,$endDate){
    $days = round((strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $n = rand(0,$days);
    return '292'.date("md",strtotime("$startDate + $n days")).rand(100,999).'0253';   
}

$myRandomNumber = randomNumber('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31');
$url = "http://www.example.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myRandomNumber);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is assuming you are POSTing the data.  If using GET (or another HTTP method) then changes will be needed.

You can give a date range you want to include for the first 4 random numbers (for example to allow for including / excluding leap years - or to keep the date before today)

Answer (score 2):

Now, if I understood correctly what you want, try this:

```
$numberAsString = '292' . mt_rand(1, 12) . mt_rand(1, 31) . mt_rand(0, 9) . mt_rand(0, 9) . mt_rand(0, 9) . '0253';
```

I saved the number as a string because I don't think PHP may handle numbers that large without using floats.

Comment: I think the 292 and 0253 are also supposed to be random

Comment: Wasn't sure about that. But the op says 'the bold is the constant number'. So I did these parts constant ;)

Comment: know i want to try to post to a page by curl

Comment: If the OP really needs valid dates for the first 4 numbers, then this will not be guaranteed to work as it can produce invalid dates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

positions 1-4 random 0000-9999

positions 5,6 (starting with the rightmost) random 01-12

positions 7,8 range 01-31

positions 9-14 random 000000-999999

I dont know whats you backend, but php format is rand (min,max)

You can merge numbers as 14-character-long string, using sprintf on positions 5,6 and 7,8 to ensure leading zero for single-digit date.

32-bit php will not support 14-decimal digits in either int or float. But it does not look like you need to do any math operations on this long number.

Answer (score 0):

Convolution & confusion all around.

```
echo '292'
  .DateTime::createFromFormat('z',rand(0,365))->format('md')
  .sprintf('%03d',rand(0,999))
  .'0253';
```

Which has the added advantage of not throwing the 000-099 randomness away as the accepted answer does.